# Ocultar TabBar e Mostrar UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, tabbarcontroller

No meu projeto eu tenho uma TableView dentro de navigation controller

(TabBar > Navigation Controller > TableView Controller)

Quando aciono o botão Editar a TabBar está sendo ocultada e mostrando o Toolbar, porém ele não está ajustando no rodapé.

Como posso ajustar isso ?

Estou usando Storyboard e Swift.

[image: Imagem mostrando TabBar]

[image: Imagem mostrando Toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para dar hidden na TabBar**

Adicione está linha no ViewDidLoad() do swift :

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

**Para mostrar o UiToolBar**
E no ViewDidLoad() tente isto aqui também

```
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
       self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
```

**Exemplo :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var toolBar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRectMake(0, 524, 320, 44))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
       self.view.addSubview(toolBar)

    }
}
```